# Angular 4 - Circular dependency detected

Tags: angular

Opening model from parent component which is existed in child component. Once child functionality completed have to call the parent component METHOD from child component.

i can call the method from child to parent component, but its through warning has Circular dependency detected..

```
Parent :
parent.html
<child></child>

Parent.ts 
import {c_Comp} from 'child.comp'
@Component({
selector: "parent",
 templateUrl: "parent.html"   
})
export class parent{
 @ViewChild{c_Comp} child : c_Comp;
 constructor(){}
 method(){
   this.child.open();       
 }    
 loadlist(){ } // Have to call from child component.
}  

Child:
import { p_Comp } from 'parent.comp';

@Component({
selector: "child",
  templateUrl: "child.html"   
})
export class child{
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => parent)) private 
  _parent:parent ) {}
  open() {
    this.notifyModel.show();
  }    
  notifyConfirm() {
   this._parent.loadlist();
  }
}  

module.ts   

import { parent } from 'parent.comp';
import { child } from 'child.comp';
@NgModule({
     declarations: [parent, child],
     imports: []
})  
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid this kind of reference, if you want to talk with a child use `@ViewChild` but if you want to do something with the parent from the child use an event (`@Output`).

Here you have an example that I did for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rltr2g

*Parent component*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <h1>Parent component</h1>
    <child (onNotify)="runOnChildNotify($event)"></child>
    <p>Times notified: {{count}}</p>
    <button (click)="openChild()">Open child</button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ParentComponent  {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child : ChildComponent = null;

  count: number = 0;

  constructor() {}

  openChild(): void {
    this.child.open();
  }

  loadList(): void {
    this.count++;
  }

  runOnChildNotify(event: any) {    
    console.log(event.message); // you will see 'hello form child component' here.
    this.loadList();
  }

}
```

*Child component*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `[Child component - Here]`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ChildComponent  {

  @Output() onNotify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  open(): void {
    this.onNotify.emit({message: 'hello from child component'});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are imported the child component in to the parent and the parent in to the child, you don't need to import those components.

Instead as long as they live in the same module, say `app.module.ts` and you put the child component's selector in the parent component's template, your code should work just fine.

Additionally for `@ViewChild` you don't need to type the child, instead use `ElementRef` or even just leave it off.

Comment: yes i put the child component's selector in the parent component's template,

but unable to access parent comp method without import.even both comp in same module.ts

Comment: why do you need to access parent's method?

Comment: for ex :
I have a customer gridlist in parent page,  have to add new customer in model by  using child component.. once successful response , have to refresh the list in parent component and also show the alert message which is existing in parent component... etc function have to trigger..

Comment: you can just pass data down from parent to child and pass data back up from child to parent?

Comment: ok.. without import i am not getting parent method in child component. can i get some sample links plz..

Comment: @ArunA ask it in a different question as for this one I don't know how you want to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Structuring the application properly can avoid circular dependency.Here in your case  this may be the reason, Import of one component/service depends on another component/service which in turn depends on the first component/service or or a pattern similar.

Comment: in my case, once functionality done in child component, have to call parent comp method, unable to call without import parent in child, which the code replicates above.